# AWS version returns bad interpreter error due to python version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

My aws version is giving bad interpreter error as below. I am working on AWS Ws amazon linux OS

```
[TSS\user@a-17vvp87saq00q ~]$ aws --version
bash: /home/user/.local/bin/aws: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
[TSS\user@a-17vvp87saq00q ~]$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

How do I link Python 3.8.5 version with the aws cli. Please guide

Comment: if you are running on EC2 instance, why are you running aws cli from your home directory? also, where is `python` running from? You don't need to *link* anything - aws will find the right executable - the one it installed. Maybe easiest is just to reinstall aws

Comment: I am running on AWS WS machine. Tried uninstall/reinstall aws but not much help

Comment: Had to edit the pythonpath in the bash_profile . With that it worked !

Comment: That should not be necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below commands. I'm using Mac.

1. Reinstall awscli using `brew reinstall awscli` command.
2. Link using `brew link --overwrite awscli` command.

This resolved error. Now I can see the version using `aws --version` command.